# Set up EFI with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I just bought a new barebone ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06WV7NB95)) and added a 250 Gig SSD + 8 GB RAM. (The point is that the hardware is entirely new).

I installed Ubuntu (and after that OpenElec just to compare and I am having exactly the same problem). When I have the Live-Stick plugged in, I can boot the live version from it as well as install from it, when I boot the PC and the stick is plugged in, I can see its boot selection.

Now after I have installed Ubuntu (or OpenElec) and I am trying to boot from the disk all I get is a black screen for 5 seconds and then my PC switches to the EFI config screen.

I can boot the live version and check my SSD, I can see there are 2 partitions and one is EXT4 and one is EFI, so the disk can be seen at there is a bootable partition.

However, it appears to me that my EFI Bios does not recognize the SSD. Because I have an option in my EFI that says "Write secure keys to disk" and when I try to do this, it says there is no file system for that.

I have used `boot info` to create a report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nwD3p6GMF9/

Now I am all out of ideas why my PC does not seem to recognize or boot Ubuntu.

Edit: As to the duplicate question flag: This is a different *question*. The anwser might also bei reEFInd, but the problem is different. Also it turned out I needed to flash my BIOS, which did not work well with my SSD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any downside to using rEFInd instead of GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760875/any-downside-to-using-refind-instead-of-grub)

Comment: How is this related to rEFInd? I don't understand?

Comment: You have an EFI problem, so have you tried to see whether rEFInd finds and can boot your currently installed Ubuntu boot?

Comment: I edited the question related to the duplicate question flag

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I needed to flash my BIOS, which did not work well with my SSD (it did not really detect it). This was a bug in ASUS' UN45 Model.